# Can't change password on Windows 7 laptop - receive error

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords

A field laptop reports the user account password has changed. We attempt to reset the password, but receive the error:

> Configuration information could not be read from the domain
>   controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or because
>   access is denied.

The laptop was not connected to the domain at the time we attempted to change the password, but if connect the laptop to a LAN connected to the DC, we receive the same error.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You should check your group policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem in an unusual way. I booted into Safe Mode, where I was allowed to login with the expired password, and opened a cmd prompt.

`> net user` only found `administrator` and `guest` accounts.

I reset the `administrator` account password, rebooted, but could not login with the new `administrator` password.

I logged in as the user account, which told me the password was expired, and this time I was able to change the password without error.

I don't know why that worked.

I later set the password to not expire.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have access to the AD to view any logs?

On the laptop try the following to prevent any cached info about the connection to the AD

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```